# Does "thread_local" work for a naked thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, posix, standards

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "~A()" << endl;
    }
};

void* f(void*)
{
    thread_local A a;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, nullptr, f, nullptr);
    this_thread::sleep_for(5min);
}
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when
>   the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only
>   objects declared `thread_local` have this storage duration.

I just wonder:

How does the C++ compiler know when a naked thread (**rather than `std::thread`**) is created and exited?

In other words:

Does the C++ standard guarantee `A::~A()` will be called after the naked thread function `f` is finished?

Comment: This is hard to answer from a C++ standard point of view, since the C++ standard doesn't have a concept of a "naked thread" the way you use it. But of course C++ threads will be implemented in some platform-specific way, and if you happen to code that same implementation directly, you may well end up getting the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard says nothing about what happens when or after you call `pthread_create`. So if you want to know about that, you'd have to look someplace other than the C++ standard. Unfortunately, the POSIX standard says nothing about C++ thread local objects. So the POSIX standard won't say anything either.

That means that whatever happens to happen on some particular platform is not guaranteed unless the documentation for that particular compiler, platform, or threading standard says something specific.